# How to scroll smoothly in thumbnails

Tags: android

I have thumbnails in my app.I used below library for thumbs.

http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

But scrolling thumbnails are not smooth.How to do this thin?

Comment: cant you use normal gridview?

Comment: no,this library matches to my requirment

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's happens when you have so much elements. Try use Android ViewHolder pattern. 
[Android ViewHolder Pattern Example](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

[Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)